# WSDL2Java Eclipse plugin BigDecimal Issue

Tags: java, eclipse, bigdecimal, wsdl2java

I'm attempting to generate Java code from a `WSDL` file. It generates the code but there seems to be an issue with one of the auto generated setter methods.

```
/**
* Auto generated setter method
* @param param Curr132
*/
public void setCurr132(java.math.BigDecimal param){
  java.lang.String totalDigitsDecimal = org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.ConverterUtil.convertToStandardDecimalNotation("13").toString();

  if (org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.ConverterUtil.compare(param,totalDigitsDecimal) > 0){
    this.localCurr132=param;
  } else {
    throw new java.lang.RuntimeException();
  }                                     
}
```

Whenever I create a `new Curr132` object and use `setCurr132`, it throws the `RuntimeException`.

The problem seems to be the '>'. If I change that to a '<' it works. Is this the correct fix?

Answer (score 0):

Most Obvious, Don't change the operator rather change the param value, because as per param value, if condition fails. i hope, you aware of what compare method returns. if not [look at here.](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/api/org/apache/axis2/databinding/utils/ConverterUtil.html#compare%28java.math.BigInteger,%20java.lang.String%29) Hence the exception thrown in the else blog.

Answer (score 0):

In Java invoke setCurr132() as folllow

`java.math.BigDecimal param=new java.math.BigDecimal(3.0E13);`
`setCurr132(param);`